# Event listener is not working with button in javascript

Tags: javascript

Before you mark this as duplicate again, let me just say I already went over to the other question and read the entire thing and tried to create the same result on my end. I tried adding the event listener to my button, but it's still not working. So I beg you to please give some other people some time to answer my question before you mark it duplicate again or delete it.

```js
var button = document.createElement("BUTTON"); // Create a <button> element
var text = document.createTextNode("CLICK ME"); // Create a text node
button.appendChild(text); // Append the text to <button>
document.body.appendChild(button);
button.addEventListener("click", clickMe, false);

function clickMe() {
  alert("Hi");
} //end of function clickMe()
```

Comment: Can you explain what the issue is?  It works when I copy and paste your exact code.

Comment: "it's not working" is not helpful - that might be why previous versions of your question were closed.  if you feel that your question is not actually a duplicate, then please describe what's different so we can best help you

Answer (score 0):

this adds the id for button

```js
var button = document.createElement("BUTTON");
button.setAttribute("id", "buttonid");
// Create a <button> element
var text = document.createTextNode("CLICK ME");       // Create a text node
button.appendChild(text);                                // Append the text to <button>
document.body.appendChild(button);
button.addEventListener("click", clickMe,false);

function clickMe() {
alert("Hi");
} //end of function clickMe
```

Comment: I'm using this on tampermonkey on www.google.com with firefox and it's not working on my end.

Comment: seems to be working here.  You'll need to provide more information as to why it isn't working on your end

Comment: It just doesn't work on www.google.com, not the brower, the website. It works on other websites. How do I add an id to the button?

Comment: Just letting you know **I was able to reproduce this error** using tampermonkey and I just want to say you are correct. A button injected into google.com shows up but is not able to be clicked. I added classes and tried to move the position but no luck. You might want to edit your question or re-ask it with an emphasis that you're using tampermonkey. Thats the only place this error occurs and it seems to be something specific with tampermonkey, not the code. There is a tampermonkey tag you can tag your question with.